# Select element with title in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I apply something to all elements now and in the future which have a title attribute set?

The reason why I want to achieve this is simple:
I have a footer in a webapp where, like many apps, I'd like to have some information written on hovering some elements.
I'd like to set this information in the title attribute of the elements I want to display information for.

So every element with a title should trigger a function on hover. Even elements that are added dynamically.

I found this to have something work on mouse enter+leave that is suposed to work for added elements:

```
$(document).on(
{
    mouseenter: function() 
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseover
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseleave
    }
}
, "*[special-selector]");
```

what's the special selector supposed to be?

Secondary question: How can I acces the $(this).attr('title')  attribute from within the scope of these 2 anonymous functions?

Any Idea? or maybe better solutions? I want too keep the html as simple as possible and avoid using the onmouseover attributes within the elements as there are LOT of them..

Comment: Do you actually need event delegation? IMO, it's not a very good idea to use document-level delegation for `mousenter/leave` handlers. It's not as bad if you can constrain the delegation to a small part of the page. But if not, I think you'd be better off binding directly to the current and new elements.

Comment: ...this is especially true if you're targeting based only on an attribute, and nothing else.

Comment: I know it's using a event that will be unused in 99% cases, but the possibilities of having to show a hint in the footer are to wide to target something more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target an element with the attribute selector:

```
$(document).on(
{
    mouseenter: function(e)
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseover
        var domNode = this,
            $object = $(domNode),
            title = domNode.title;
        $object.addClass('hover');
        console.log(title);
    },
    mouseleave: function(e)
    {
        //stuff to do on mouseleave
        var domNode = this,
            $object = $(domNode),
            title = domNode.title;
        $object.removeClass('hover');
        console.log(title);
    }
}
, "[title]");
```

[(Simple) JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jpDRY/1/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: When using this signature, you need to put the function as value within the plain object after `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. See **http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data**

Comment: What's the last function for ?

Comment: Ok, this works, I'm a bit surprised about the 'this' result, I woudn't have expected this event to target the specific element and not simply the document, thanks!